# Mobile Intel 4 series Express Graphics

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

I have an older laptop which I am trying to install Ubuntu on.  When I use the first option "Try Ubuntu" the display goes to black and nothing happens after that point.  If I use the second option "Try Ubuntu (Safe Graphics)" the laptop boots up to the GUI but the display is set to low resolution (1024x768) and cannot be changed in settings. In settings the graphics field shows "llvmpipe(LLVM 9.0.1, 128 bit". I believe the display driver for this old Intel chipset is not being found or is not available.  How do I fix this problem?  Where can a find a display driver for this older chipset?

Version 20.04 LTS.
Graphics chipset is Mobile Intel 4 Series Express

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I noticed when I shined a flashlight at the black screen there was an image on the screen.  It appears the back light on the laptop's screen was not on.  It was fixed by using the laptop's keyboard screen brightness keys to change the brightness.